# MySQL INSERT syntax giving a weird error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm facing a very weird issue with a MySQL database. I'm trying to insert some values into a table that I've created but facing an error 1064. I've changed every single part of my syntax. Here's verbatim what I've been typing on my terminal:

```
mysql -u root -p
CREATE DATABASE robotics
USE robotics
CREATE TABLE `2017marea` (
    `Team` INT(25) NOT NULL, 
    `Match` INT(25) NOT NULL, 
    `Auto` INT(25) NOT NULL, 
    `Gear` INT(25) NOT NULL, 
    `Kpa` INT(25) NOT NULL, 
    `Climb` INT(25) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO 2017marea (Team, Match, Auto, Gear, Kpa, Climb) VALUES (1721, 1, 3, 5, 5, 1);
```

At this point, MySQL will return me an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Match, Auto, Gear, Kpa, Climb) VALUES (1721, 1, 3, 5, 5, 1);
```

I know that this is a syntax error. However, changing my values syntax doesn't seem to affect the error at all, and furthermore nothing I do seems to be stopping the error. I've tried surrounding every value in every different type of quotes or ticks that I could think of, and the initial columns also. I'm confused, what's happening here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Match` is a reserved keyword in MySQL.  You can get around the error by placing it in backticks, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO 2017marea (Team, `Match`, Auto, Gear, Kpa, Climb)
VALUES (1721, 1, 3, 5, 5, 1);
```

I noticed that when your created your table, you placed *every* column name in backticks.  This prevented you from seeing the error at that time.  Had you done this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE `2017marea` (
    Team INT(25) NOT NULL, 
    Match INT(25) NOT NULL, 
    Auto INT(25) NOT NULL, 
    Gear INT(25) NOT NULL, 
    Kpa INT(25) NOT NULL, 
    Climb INT(25) NOT NULL
);
```

you would have hit the error before even creating the table.

In general you should avoid using MySQL reserved keywords for your database, table, and column names.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I didn't realize - I'm rather new to MySQL in the manner I'm using it.

Answer (score 2):

The word "Match" in the INSERT statement should be put in `` I think